# When storing variable always else statement value is only stored php mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Trying to save the status its always storing only else value

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM videos";
$select_query = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($select_query)){
    $id=$row['id'];
    $url = $row['url'];
    $current_views =  $row['current_views'];
    $start_date=  $row['start_date'];
    $end_date =  $row['end_date'];
    $views_ordered =  $row['views_ordered'];
    $views_delivered = $row['views_delivered'];
    $video_id = substr($url, strpos($url, "=") + 1);   
    $jsonviews=file_get_contents('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=contentDetails,statistics&id='.$video_id.'&key=AIzaSyC1Rt_ujhmXFGf_m7c3HnpSK9qE_hFt1t0');
    $views_data = json_decode($jsonviews, true);
    $video_view = $views_data['items'][0]['statistics']['viewCount'];
    $result = $video_view > $views_delivered ? 'increase' :'decrease';
    echo $result;
    $query = "UPDATE videos SET " ;
    $query .="views_delivered='{$video_view}', ";
    $query .="status='{$result}' ";
    $query .="WHERE id={$id}";
    $create_comment_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
    if(! $create_comment_query)
    {
        die("Query failed".mysqli_error($connection));
    }
}
```

When I am echoing the result its shown correct only but when I am storing its always storing only else stmt value;

Comment: *"only else"* - what "else" is that?

Comment: i cannot see an else statement here. I can see SQL injection waiting to happen though

Comment: i am unable to see `else` part?

Comment: @Fred-ii- I have written it with ternary operator

Comment: check for errors then via php's error reporting and error checking on the queries.

Comment: You need to print what you get from `$jsonviews` and debug it yourself.

Comment: so you want to say that `echo $result;` working fine but storing it is not working? yes? where you stored it?

Comment: you should add an `echo $query;` to see the actual sql query - there might be the problem

Comment: @AlivetoDie yes its always storing storing only decrease

Comment: You know all this code is in the `while` loop. it will go through each record from your database

Comment: @Akintunde yeah I need to check every row and update it

Comment: type here:- `$result = $video_view > $views_delivered `  need to be `$result = $video_view -> $views_delivered `

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the ternary operator, however did you checked the data coming in  $video_view and $views_delivered ? i know you probably did but maybe

Comment: @KrunalLimbad video_view i will get views form youtube api and views_delivered  from database I have tried by changing everything while echoing the query its showing correct only but while saving its saving increase or decrease only but not both

Comment: @KrunalLimbad  here is the echo value of query UPDATE videos SET views_delivered='326476', status='increase' WHERE id=1UPDATE videos SET views_delivered='3682582', status='decrease' WHERE id=2  but its storing only increase

Comment: okay that what ternary operator do, what is you requirement if i may ask

Comment: @KrunalLimbad actualy am using now of condition  if ($video_view >= $views_delivered) {
               $result = 'increase';
         } else{
            $result = 'decrease';
      }  its always printing increase now in database but while echoing its showing decrease in query but dont know why only printing increase

Comment: i m sorry, but i dont see any problem in code, it is running as it has written,.

Comment: @KrunalLimbad is it running for you properly